# ORDER BY date but keep GROUP BY groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query grouping by ClientID and Location:

```
SELECT
    lph.ClientID
    ,lph.LocationID
    ,MAX(c.ClientName) AS ClientName
    ,MAX(cp.ClientName) AS ClientPartnerName
    ,MAX(c.BillingContactName) AS BillingContactName
    ,MAX(c.BillingEmail) AS BillingEmail
FROM [billing].[TEST_LicensePackageHeader] lph
    LEFT JOIN [app].[TEST_Client] c
        ON lph.ClientID = c.ClientID
    LEFT JOIN [billing].[TEST_LicensePackageClientPartner] lpcp
        ON lph.PackageID = lpcp.PackageID
    LEFT JOIN [app].[TEST_Client] cp --client partner
        ON lpcp.ClientPartnerID = cp.ClientID
WHERE lph.LicenseExpirationDate BETWEEN @FilterStartDate AND @FilterEndDate
    AND ( ((LEN(@ClientPartnerSearchString) > 0) AND (cp.ClientName LIKE '%' + @ClientPartnerSearchString + '%') )
    OR ((LEN(@ClientPartnerSearchString) = 0)) )
GROUP BY lph.ClientID, lph.LocationID
ORDER BY lph.ClientID, lph.LocationID, MAX(lph.LicenseExpirationDate)
```

I would like to ORDER BY the MAX(LicenseExpirationDate) DESC such that the groupings by ClientID show up in order of MAX(LicenseExpirationDate) DESC.

Looking at only these 3 columns, I need it to be grouped as follows:

```
| ClientID | LocationID | MAX(LicenseExpirationDate) |
----------------------------------------------------
| 4        | 3          | 01/03/2019                 |
| 4        | 7          | 01/17/2020                 |
| 1        | 1          | 02/04/2018                 |
| 1        | 3          | 07/13/2018                 |
| 2        | 8          | 09/22/2015                 |
| 2        | 3          | 01/30/2017                 |
```

Basically I just need MAX(LicenseExpirationDate) to take precedent in the sort order, while keeping the groupings by ClientID and LocationID together.

Hope this makes sense. I'm not sure how to do this in SQL server. Thanks!

Comment: Does you need to sort by `MAX(LicenseExpirationDate)` per user regardless the location of this date? if so obtain `MAX(LicenseExpirationDate) OVER (PATITION BY ClientID)` additionally in CTE, and use this CTE instead of  `[billing].[TEST_LicensePackageHeader] AS lph` in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order by max(max(LicenseExpirationDate)) over (partition by clientId) desc,
         clientId,
         max(LicenseExpirationDate) asc
```

This orders the clients first by the maximum `LicenseExpirationDate` over the entire client.  Then it sorts within each client by `LicenseExpirationDate` for each row.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. Only thing is LicenseExpirationDate needs to be MAX(LicenseExpirationDate) in the last order by column bc it is not grouped by.